# Modern OpenGL problems with Orthographic Projection

Tags: opengl, glsl, orthographic

I'm going right to the point. I already did some reasearch and I still didn't figure out this.

I have a program that draws a cube each face with a color.
Then I rotate this cube in the Y-axis and also in the X-axis (-45 and +45 respectively).

The problem is that it's not rendering as I was expecting, the cube is getting clipped at some point.

The code:

```
projection = glm::ortho(-1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f);

camera = glm::lookAt(
                     glm::vec3(+0.0f,+0.0f,+1.0f),
                     glm::vec3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f),
                     glm::vec3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f)
                     );

model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
model = glm::rotate(model, -45.0f, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
model = glm::rotate(model, +45.0f, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

mvp = projection * camera * model;
```

[image: Cube rendered clipped]

All the vertices I am defining are made with ±0.25. So I thought at least that with my these values of zNear and zFar they would still fit in the volume, but when I change the line

```
projection = glm::ortho(-1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f);
```

for

```
projection = glm::ortho(-1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f, +2.0f, -1.0f);
```

it works just fine

[image: Correct rendered]

But it doesn't work with

```
projection = glm::ortho(-1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f, -2.0f);
```

Can someone explain me why? I mean, I know that if I put more values the projection cube will have bigger volume so it will render just fine. I knowthe the bottom right vertex is outside the cube with zNear and zFar to +1.0 and -1.0 (the vertex value is something like 1.76 after the application of the matrix) but if I extend the zFar cube to -2.0f it should fit just right, shouldn't?

I tried to read something on the Red Book and also Peter Shirley book Fundamentals of Computer Graphics. And even made the matrix by myself, but with the same results.

Anyway, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is happening, is that the cube is clipped by the camera's far clip plane.

Anything that is beyond the far clip plane will not be rendered.

In your original code, the far clip plane is set to +1, which is very close to the camera.
Anything beyond 1 unit will not be rendered.

In your working code, you set the far clip plane to +2, so anything beyond 2 units will not be rendered.

As the cube is closer then 2 units to the camera, the whole cube is rendered.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
But I thought that the near plane is +1
`ortho (T const &left, T const &right, T const &bottom, T const &top, T const &zNear, T const &zFar)`

So, that's why I've put the far plane to -2 to try and see, cause by the calculations of the matrix against the vertex the Z component from bottom left vertex  goes from +0.25 to -1.75. so I understand that is being clipped by the far plane. But when I put the far plane to -2 it still happens.

Comment: The purpose of the far plane, is to define the furthest distance the camera can render to. By setting it to -2, the far plane is now not only behind the camera, but behind the near plane (which is usually not what you want). What you want instead, is a far plane with a positive value that is greater then the near plane. As an example, I usually have a near plane of 0.01, and a far plane of 100.

Comment: OK, probably I'm with a misconception for where the farplane is located. Cause I thought that putting the camera at (0,0,1) and looking at (0,0,0) would make the near plane pretty close and the far plane behind it but still with the camera able to see it. 



So, putting the near value as 0.01 and far as 100 I would have to define all my vertices  component between these two values right?

Comment: Sounds like you are a bit unsure about how the projection matrix works (correct me if I am wrong). I would recommend having a look at this tutorial: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/#The_Model__View_and_Projection_matrices

It goes though what the projection and view matrices are, how they work, and how to use them.

Comment: @AntonioRibeiro: The values for `near` and `far` are distances relative to the "camera" (actually there is no camera and things are globally moved around to that it is, as if the camera was placed at 0,0,0). Which means that the actual scene transformations to move things around (including the "camera") are not with respect to the clip planes.

Comment: Damn! Thank you so much @datenwolf  now everything got clear!
Also thanks Sir.Tiddlesworth your explanation and link helped!

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you want the near plane to come before the far plane.  I'm not sure what would happen if you, for some reason, made the far plane negative and the near plane positive...  Try swapping them.

Comment: As far as I remember the near plane is the first one the +1.0f and the far plane is the -1.0f, isn't? So by putting the camera in the position 0,0,1 so the near is coming before the far. Or did I go fulltard now?

Comment: The near/far values are relative to the camera, IIRC, so negative is behind the camera and positive is forward.